# How to access object property from a string containing brackets

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I am trying to parse a given string that contains brackets, indicating object properties are involved in getting the value from an object.

The object property is `someobj.pform.options.foo = "somestring";`

Using javascript/jQuery, how can I accomplish this? The problem I have with the method I've devised (below) does not reassign the object within the loop.

```
var uiobject = {};
uiobject.name = "options[foo]";

var objectvalue = "";
var props = uiobject.name.replace(/\]/g, '').split('[');
var temp = someobj.pform;

for(var z=0;z<props.length;z++) {
    if(temp.hasOwnProperty[ (props[z]) ]) {
        if(z == (props.length - 1)) {
            objectvalue = temp[ props[z] ];
        } else {
            temp = temp[ (props[z]) ];
        }
    }
}
console.log("value: "+objectvalue);
```

Comment: please add the object, you like to access and the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might be misunderstanding `hasOwnProperty`. If you negate the predicate (or remove that block completely), it works:

```js
var uiobject = {};
uiobject.name = "options[foo][bar]";

var objectvalue = "";
var props = uiobject.name.replace(/\]/g, '').split('[');
var temp = {options:{foo:{bar:"baz"}}};

for(var z=0;z<props.length;z++) {
    if(!temp.hasOwnProperty[ (props[z]) ]) {
        if(z == (props.length - 1)) {
            objectvalue = temp[ props[z] ];
        } else {
            temp = temp[ (props[z]) ];
        }
    }
}
console.log("value: "+objectvalue);
```

Comment: I truly don't understand why your solution works. My goal was to check for the existence of the property before trying to access it (been there, done that). So why negating the method call works is something I totally need to sit down and grok!

Comment: Negating the hasOwnProperty() method still doesn't make sense to me. I have replaced it with `code`typeof temp[prop[z]] != 'undefined'`code`, which does what I originally wanted to do